# LiPo drone battery first charge voltage rate

Tags: battery

Does a LiPo drone battery need a specific voltage rate for the first charge?
If so, how much voltage does it need?
Thanks.

Comment: Depends on the battery - what did it say in the user manual, can you share an image of the battery and any details you know about it?

Comment: Where is the original charger?

Comment: Well, I don't have it with me. And I don't remember its name. :(

Comment: How is it configured? 3s 4p ?

Comment: Use a charge rate of 1C, ie. if the battery is 2200mAh, use a charge current of 2200mA (give or take it doesn't need to be exact. Make sure you have a balance charger if the pack is any more than 1s (it will have a balance lead).